# Wrong installed virtualenv

Tags: python, django, windows, virtualenv

I wanted to intall virtualenv in CMD (Windows 11). Unfortunately it was downloaded in the place I did not want to install it (it was supposed to be installed on D but it was installed on C. Also the folder i was expecting to be created was not created. What should I do to completly get rid of it from my computer?

That is what occured after typing "virtualenv django" in CMD (django is the name of the folder which was supposed to be created):

```
created virtual environment CPython3.11.0.final.0-64 in 1709ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=D:\django, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\mmilk\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.3.1, setuptools==65.6.3, wheel==0.38.4
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
```

I chose the folder I wanted to install the program typed "virtualenv django". Later on the program introduced me where is the whole data which was created. It was on C instead of D.

1. Is it true if I turn off the computer the virtualenv gets deactivated?
2. Can I download it once again but this time on the completly different drive? For example the wrong virtualenv on C, the correct virtualenv on D. I'd only work on the virtualenv on the D drive.

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform you, Python has an in-built virtual environment.

You just have to create and activate it with the following commands :

```
# For creating virtual environment ...

python -m venv env       # For windows
python3 -m venv env      # For any linux distros

# For activating ...

env\Scripts\activate     # For windows
source env/bin/activate  # For any linux distros
```

Comment: Does it allow me to code with django? I can do it in the terminal or cmd?

Comment: Yes, definitely. After all, Django is built on python, so it supports Django.

Comment: I have watched a tutorial about it and i' ve got some questions: 1. Every time I make a new project I have to instal django? 2. The commands you typed above are the commands that I have to type in the terminal of my project?

Comment: For every project, you have to create new virtual environment as the package dependencies are different respective to projects

Comment: I followed all the steps in the tutorial and the server was running properly. After some time when I refreshed the website there is written "this site can't be reached" do you maybe know how to solve this problem?